# html element adaptable when browser window resize using bootstrap in html?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to use bootstrap for the div element with css changes. i tried with col-xs-* and col-md-* for the div but it not working. I need a help regarding when the browser resize it adaptable to the page.

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">   
  <div class="pull-right metrics-section ng-scope">
       <span class="metrics-header-section col-sm-2 ng-scope" 
     ng-repeat="items in metrics">              
              <p class="ng-binding">{{items.value}}</p>
              <p>{{items.name}}</p>
              <p class=" metrics-divider"> </p>
       </span>    </div> </body>
```

.css:

```
.metrics-section {
  background-color: #b6b5b5;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 31px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  }

.metrics-header-section {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #003265;
  width: 155px;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 1px; }

.metrics-header-section p:not(.metric-divider) {
    margin: 2px;
     width: auto;
     text-align: center;
     display:block;
}

.metrics-header-section p:first-child {
    font-size:13px;
    color:#3D6186;
 }

 .metrics-header-section p:nth-child(2) {
     font-size:9px;
     color:#3D6186;
 }
span.metrics-header-section > p.metrics-divider {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 25px;
  border-right: 1px solid #003265;
  height: 20px;
}

.metrics-header-section:nth-child(4) > p.metrics-divider {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 15px;
  border-right: none;
  height: 20px;
}
```

.js:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.metrics = [
    {name : "COMPLETED", value : "12"},
    {name : "EXCEEDING", value : "18"},
    {name : "APPROACHING", value : "10"},
    {name : "AVAILABLE", value : "40"}
    ];
});
```

The output as follows:

```
   12           18          10           40
COMPLETED | EXCEEDING | APPROACHING | AVAILABLE
```

Comment: Make sure you use the classes "container" and "row" as well. Also, make sure the CSS is actually loading.

Comment: @coopersita Yes i tried that also it not working. can you please give the sample of the same.

Comment: If you tried it, then perhaps your CSS isn't loading. If you view the source in the browser, click on the link for the bootstrap CSS.

Comment: No its loading but the output is not look like as i given similar to above. Please help me with example.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/eyTLFz7Z9YDJta3dczAs?p=preview this is the plunker link

Answer (score 0):

You need to load Boostrap's CSS, not just the Javascript. Add this to the `<head>` tag:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: i already include but it not working as per my requirement in the output section in question. i alrdy updated the code in the plunker. please help me with that demo. http://plnkr.co/edit/eyTLFz7Z9YDJta3dczAs?p=preview

Comment: The plunker you provided doesn't have the bootstrap CSS on it, so the CSS in it is not working on it either.